# Saving XML files with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im working on a Rails project that should create XMl files, or to be more specific
use existing XMl templates and put content from the database in it.

So i dont need to create the xml structure, basically just rendering a template with content.
What would be the smartest way to do that?

So far i have a file.xml.erb in my layout folder
and i have a custom route "/renderXML" that does

```
def renderXML 
  @reading_question = ReadingQuestion.find(params[:id])
  render :file => 'layouts/question.xml'
end
```

This works, but i also want to save the file, not only show it (actually viewing it is not really needed).
For saving i found this

```
File.open('fixed.xml','w'){|f| f.write builder.to_xml}
```

How do i access the rendered file and save it with some method like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
s = render_to_string :file => 'layouts/question.xml'
File.open('fixed.xml','w'){|f| f.write s}
render :text => s
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach :

> send_data fixed, :type => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8;', :disposition =>
>   "attachment; filename=fixed.xml"