# How to save ruby builder generated xml instead of rendering it in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, builder

I have a builder that renders xml when create is called.  How can I skip the rendering step, but save the xml to the filesystem?

```
def create
    @server = Server.new(params[:server])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @server.save
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully created server."
            format.xml
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end  
    end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving XML files with Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163385/saving-xml-files-with-rails)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The XML builder can write its data to any object supporting the `<<` operator.  In your case `String` and `File` objects seem to be the most interesting.

Using a string would look something like this:

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new  # Uses the default string target
# TODO: Add your tags
xml_data = xml.target!  # Returns the implictly created string target object

file = File.new("my_xml_data_file.xml", "wb")
file.write(xml_data)
file.close
```

But since the `File` class supports the `<<` operator as well, you can write the data directly into a file:

```
file = File.new("my_xml_data_file.xml", "wb")
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new target: file
# TODO: Add your tags
file.close
```

For further details have a look at [the documentation of XmlMarkup](http://builder.rubyforge.org/classes/Builder/XmlMarkup.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is so good. you can also create a path to store all the xmls in a given folder so that the application is organized.

```
file = File.new("some_path/my_xml_data_file.xml", "w")
```

Thank you Daniel

Comment: Please could you tell me the reason for this 

 file = File.new("xml/experiment.xml", "w")
    # creating the builder file for the xml
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new :target => file
    # xml tags
    xml.instruct! 
    xml.EXPERIMENT_SET {
        xml.alias("#{@experiment.alias}")
        xml.center_name "#{@experiment.center_name}"
    }  


I get an output like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EXPERIMENT_SET><alias>ZAP430</alias><center_name></center_name></EXPERIMENT_SET>

Which is not a neat XML, all tags are displayed in a single line.

Comment: Use `xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new (:target => file, :indent => 2)` to get a pretty XML. Notice `:indent => 2` when creating builder.